# How can I use the `@` symbol in a twitter bot without mentioning a user?

Tags: r, twitter, bots, twitter-oauth

Using twitter in the normal way, you can post an `@` symbol without tagging someone by using `@@`. E.g. `@_wurli` would show as a mention, but `@@_wurli`, while giving the same *text*, would not be  mention.

I want to know how I can achieve this using a bot. I am using the {rtweet} package in the R language.

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t know about the double-@ trick. I’ve always used zero-width space instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure where I read about it. Tweet parsing rules seem fairly sparsely documented. Although if you're versed in Java, Ruby, Javascript or Objective C you can check out the public [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) repo, which is what Twitter apparently uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether or not there's an intended approach to for dealing with these. However, a good workaround I've found is to simply insert a zero-width space between the `@` and the rest of the text. This also works for hashtags:

```
tweets <- c("@not_a_user", "#notatag")

zero_width_space <- "\U200B"

tweets <- tweets |>
  gsub(x = _, "@", paste0("@", zero_width_space)) |>
  gsub(x = _, "#", paste0("#", zero_width_space))
```

The only potential issue is that this adds to the number of characters in the tweet. However if you're only transforming a few characters per tweet this is most likely not going to be an issue.